# SELECT into deep structure

Tags: abap, opensql

I am relatively new to ABAP and so I still need to get used to internal tables and the like,
so currently I am a little bit struggling with how to use SQL in ABAP to fill a nested structure.

For example:

```
TYPES: BEGIN of <<mystructure>>,
         someID type sometype,
         relatedItemsInDataModel type table of sometabletype,
       END of <<mystructure>>.
DATA wa type <<mystructure>>.

<<SELECT INTO STATEMENT>>

DATA(lv_json) = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data = wa compress abap_true ... ).
```

So basically, I've got a table (A) in the dictionary which has a one-to-many relationship to another table (B) and I want to select all items in A and for every item in A I want to select all related items in B for that record.

The reason I wanna do this is because I later on want to convert that data to JSON looking like:

```
[
 {
  "someID": "someValue",
  "relatedItemsInDataModel": [{...}, {...}]
 },
 {
  "someID": "someValue2",
  "relatedItemsInDataModel": [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
 },
 ...
]
```

So, am I approaching this the right way in the first place and how can I achieve what I just described?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to fill a nested structured structure with standard SQL as the SQL is relational and not hierarchical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT`s only retrieve flat tables. Your therefore need to retrieve nested data in multiple steps and assemble it in the ABAP code.

Your example could look like this:

```
DATA the_ids_i_want TYPE RANGE OF sometype.

SELECT <field-list>
  FROM table_a
  INTO TABLE @DATA(selection_a)
  WHERE some_id IN @the_ids_i_want.

SELECT <field-list>
  FROM table_b
  INTO TABLE @DATA(selection_b)
  WHERE parent_id IN @the_ids_i_want.

LOOP AT selection_a INTO DATA(row_a).

  DATA(result_row) =
    VALUE <<mystructure>>(
      some_id = row_a-some_id ).

  LOOP AT selection_b INTO DATA(row_b)
      WHERE parent_id = row_a-some_id.
    
    INSERT VALUE #(
        field_a = row_b-field_a
        ... )
      INTO TABLE row_a-relatedItemsInDataModel.

  ENDLOOP.

ENDLOOP.
```

There are a lot of aspects that can be optimized, depending on your data. For example, the `WHERE` conditions may vary depending on the type of foreign key relations, you may want to consider adding sorted keys to the internal table to speed up the `LOOP ... WHERE` lookup, there may be shorter variants for the assembly, using `FOR` instead of `LOOP AT`, etc. - but basically, this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found a similar solution myself but your answer explains it perfectly. Appreciate it.